# android test app..toast doesnot work

Tags: android

I am a novice in android and trying to create a small app.

my java file :

```
//creating object for imagebutton class
ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonone);

 //creating onclick listener
mainButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //show message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SkeletonActivity.this, "Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show(); 
    }
});
```

**XML:**

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/dog8" />
```

where imageButton's id = imageButtonone.

I'm not able to print "Button pressed".
Kindly help!

Comment: please show your xml part where you declared  ImageButton.

Comment: good word novice..happy to know new word.

Comment: @freshDroid
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dog8" />

Comment: Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) maybe your code does not reach to onClick method. check if your mainButton is null or not.

2) in eclipse menu: project-> clean (your project)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!!
will follow the steps and reply shortly!
thanks again!:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Abccls extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //@Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if(view == btn)
          Toast.makeText(this, "It is a toast ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in setOnClickListener do **View.OnClickListener**. I think this will solve the problem.

```
 //creating object for imagebutton class
 ImageButton mainButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonone);

//creating onclick listener
 mainButton.setOnClickListener(new **View.OnClickListener()** {

@Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //show message
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SkeletonActivity.this, "Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

});

Comment: your solution did not solve my actual problem.
The code you gave was just an alternate to my code
anyways thanks!:-)

Answer (score 0):

check your Image Button is null or not ? Did you get any exception ?

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody
I just cleaned my project and it worked:-)